# Start sentence with "Second" and "importantly"

Tags: commas, list-order

I am writing a thesis and want to emphasis the second point I make when presenting two arguments.

> Second, importantly technology induced employment falls are not the result of an industry declining.

So *importantly* refers to the point I am making. The sentence seems weird to me. Shall I put the comma before or after *importantly* or is something else wrong here?

Comment: This is really an editorial question of style and so not suitable for an English Language Usage question.  It needs editing, but for stylistic reasons.  It is what I'll call a concatenation explosion:  you have a compound adjective ("technology induced" = induced by technology), followed by a compound noun ("employment falls" = "falls in employment").  So why not "falls in employment induced by technology"?  But hang on:  what's so "important" about saying that something caused by technology is not caused by the decline of industry?  It's obvious:  you already said it was technology induced.

Comment: Is the first point not important?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way seems to me to say

> Second, and importantly, technology-induced employment falls...

This makes more of "importantly" while still allowing the list-based "Second".

[Note that the compound adjective describing falls in employment needs a hyphen.]

Comment: Yes. These two pragmatic markers (the first, and it must be listed first, structural, the second evaluative) need the 'and' (or 'but by no means of lesser importance' etc).

Answer (score 3):

I would start with “Secondly,” and avoid saying that a point is more important in favor of demonstrating its importance and allowing the reader to come to his/her own conclusions. Also, generally speaking, one’s points should be given in order of escalating importance.